# Dell Latitude D510 isn't booting Ubuntu from a USB

Tags: dell, live-usb, boot-failure

I pressed F12 at start up, and I selected 'Boot from USB".
The screen then fades out, and the Windows XP logo appears (Indicating it has not been loaded and it has loaded from the hard drive instead).
Can anyone help me with this? I need help asap since I need ubuntu to fix a problem on my laptop.

Comment: did you checked out your BIOS settings? is your USB is the first boot device priority? else try changing the ports

Comment: have you tested the usb on another computer?

Comment: @ashutosh I tried everything you mentioned, none of it worked :(. The USB is set to highest priority, and I have tried all my ports and it didn't work

Comment: How did u make the ubuntu usb? there might be a problem with the procedure.....

Comment: @benji there is nothing wrong with the usb, I have had this problem on multiple usb's on the D510.

Comment: @Ashu I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i mean how did u burn the ubuntu iso on the usb?? also many pendrives like some old models kingston seagate etc dont boot ubuntu

Comment: I think then something is wrong either with the ISO you downloaded or with the installer your are making USB bootable with

Comment: @Ashu I just dragged it to the USB.

Comment: i think theres the problem

Comment: check this http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: how would I burn it to the USB?

Comment: i already gave the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download USB Installer in this page http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button and follow the instructions on this other page http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows to burn the .iso image correctly and install ubuntu. You can't just drag the .iso image to your USB because that's "just another file" in the usb, not and installer. You want to boot from your USB and you can't do it just by dragging the .iso in your USB. Follow the instructions and you'll be fine. It's easy. Have fun!